# Connect between Multiple tables Sqlite Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, backend

I build a mobile app and i use sqlite to store my data locally, this is how the structure of my data looks (in my mind) :

[image]

for now i can make the grey part, but i didn't find a way to connect the blue with the grey,

Comment: Are you planning to do it from scratch or using a ORM like sqfentity or moor? Check about one to many relationship and primary keys

Comment: i'm planning to do it from scratch, i try to find a repository to understand a little bit how it works

Comment: Or should i use Firebase instead ??

Comment: Well that depends on what you aim for, do you plan to work online or offline? Want to create a copy and save it in the cloud?
If offline then use SQFLite package and see how to create a db, if online try firebase or AppWire

Comment: ok, today i find Sqfentity repository https://github.com/hhtokpinar/sqfEntity but i struggle to open it on android studio. - the idea behind firebase is i was thinking about security and storage,

Comment: Struggle how? The Readme has a basic tutorial about how to generate the tables based on the conditions you want, I think if you want security you could try hive https://pub.dev/packages/hive, maybe with some code of what have you tried we can help you more

Comment: got it, thank  you

Answer (score 0):

Create a different table containing only experiences, with a column that shows whose experience it is. So you can search with name in the table and get the experiences of the person. Editing and adding experiences can be done in the same way. Structure is as follows:

```
Experiences:
 - Name
 - Job Title
 - Tasks
 - Company Name
 - City
```

Comment: can you explain a little how to do it in flutter ?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i need a " one to many relationship database " , should i use firebase or sqlite ?

Comment: Frankly, you can use whichever you feel more comfortable with. It's just that the way it works will differ. You'd have to create sub-classes and sub-collections in firebase, so it's more accessible and easy-to-understand, kinda? In SQL, different tables are for different attributes which are referenced with the primary key. Also, you'd need to know a bit of php to use SQL.

Comment: Oh, and its easier to set up firebase as there are plenty if vids if you need help